# Can you use $index outside of ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Like so:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="priority in priorities" ng-class="{active: {{$index}} == {{routeParams.priorityId - 1}} }"></div>

<a class="carousel-control left" ng-hide="!goals.length" href="#myCarousel" ng-click="changePriorityIdParam($index)" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>

app.controller("PriorityDetailController", function ($http, $scope, $location, $routeParams) {
    console.log("PriorityDetailController - priorityId: " + $routeParams.priorityId);
    getPriorityForPriorityId($http, $scope, $routeParams);

    $scope.changePriorityIdParam = function(index) {
        console.log("changePriorityIdParam() - index: " + index);
        $location.path('/priority/' + index);
        $location.replace();
    };
})
```

Comment: no $index is restricted just to ng-repeat

Comment: Can I make a copy of $index and get it to the PriorityDetailController somehow? :/

Answer (score 0):

No, that doesn't make any sense. Which index dou you want to copy, the first, the last, all of them? You're doing something really wrong with that carousel.

Write a filter on the priorites collection which will get your active element.

Or something like this:

```
$scope.changePriorityIdParam = function() {
    var index = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.priorities, function ( priority, idx) {
        if ( priority == routeParams.priorityId - 1 ) {
            index = idx;
        }
    });
    console.log("changePriorityIdParam() - index: " + index);
    $location.path('/priority/' + index);
    $location.replace();
};
```

Comment: i'm trying to get my carousel's #item.active to match the current $location.path when the user clicks the left or right carousel buttons.

Comment: Listen, Cole. It isn't crazy. The specs I have ask for an indication as to which slide you are on out of how many pictures. I can get the total from the length of the data. However, to display which of the images is on display-- it's ($index + 1) in the view, I need $index outside the view as well. Congrats on being the top result of my search. It just seems there isn't a short and simple way to accomplish what we were looking for. Not that this answer is insufficient-- it is.